# how can I take csv row's first item as a list name in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file like this and I want to take

A1,R,N,R,U,N,N,R,U,R,R

A2,R,U,R,R,N,N,R,N,N,N

B1,R,N,R,R,R,N,N,N,R,U

Now I want to get a list like this:

A1=[R,N,R,U,N,N,R,U,R,R]

A2=[R,U,R,R,N,N,R,N,N,N]

B1=[R,N,R,R,R,N,N,N,R,U]

how can I do that?

```
for x in range(len(a)):
        b = a[x].split(",")     
        doc_line.append(b)


for x in range(len(doc_line)):
    print(doc_line[x])

for x in doc_line:
        engine.append(x[0])             
        rel.append(x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read row-wise from a csv file, below is the code for that.

```
from csv import reader

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    read_csv = reader(csv_file)

    for row in read_csv:
        print(row)
```

Comment: but it does not take the first item as a list name.

Comment: do you want to create a list with name = column name ??